# Jasmine spy inside rxjs.switchMap

Tags: angular, rxjs, jasmine

I have a component that allows to confirm an event and undo the confirmation through the following function:

```
constructor(private service: Service, private snackbarService: MatSnackBar) {}

confirm(id: number): void {
    this.service.confirm(id).pipe(
      switchMap(success => {
        const ref = this.snackbarService.open('Confirmed successfully', 'Undo confirm');
        return forkJoin([of(success), ref.afterDismissed()]);
      }),
      filter(([cancelable, dismiss]) => cancelable && dismiss.dismissedByAction),
      switchMap(() => this.service.unconfirm(id)),
      tap(() => console.log('called'))
    ).subscribe(() => {
      this.snackbarService.open('Undone successfully', 'Close');
    });
}
```

On runtime it works fine, but I have trouble to test it with jasmine.

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    const serviceMock = {
      confirm: (id: number) => of(true),
      unconfirm: (id: number) => of(true)
    };
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TestComponent],
      imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MatSnackBarModule
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: Service, useValue: serviceMock }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
});

it('when confirming and canceling action, should show action canceled success snackbar', () => {
    const service = TestBed.inject(Service);
    spyOn(service, 'confirm').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(service, 'unconfirm').and.callThrough();

    const id = 1;

    component.confirm(id);

    expect(service.confirm).toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith(id);
    let snackbar = document.querySelector('simple-snack-bar');
    expect(snackbar).toBeTruthy();

    snackbar?.querySelector('button')?.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(service.unconfirm).toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith(id);
});
```

The log `called` is here but the test fails:

> Expected spy unconfirm to have been called only once, and with given args:
> [ 1 ]
> But it was never called.

Seems like jasmine catches `confirm` spy but not `unconfirm`, any idea why? They have to be called only once each

Answer (score 0):

Try and spy on the snack bar service instead of clicking in the DOM

```
const snackbarService = TestBed.inject(MatSnackBar);

spyOn(snackbarService, 'open').and.callReturn(of(dismiss.dismissedByAction));
```

Comment: I tried but this changes nothing to the error message

Comment: Try changing forkJoin to combineLatest instead as forkJoin wont emit if both observables have not completed.

Comment: This doesn't change anything either. I have to wait for both observables to emit before continue, otherwise I don't know if the user clicked on the action (ref.afterDismissed()). Moreover, both observables emitted a value since the log 'called' is visible. It works on runtime and I think it works on tests, but jasmine doesn't see it

Comment: Try spying on the snack bar service and returning `dismiss.dismissedByAction`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `click` is not completely done. You can try to add `fakeAsync` to the test and perform a `tick()` after click. Like so:

```
it('when confirming and canceling action, should show action canceled success snackbar', fakeAsync(() => {
    const service = TestBed.inject(Service);
    spyOn(service, 'confirm').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(service, 'unconfirm').and.callThrough();

    const id = 1;

    component.confirm(id);

    expect(service.confirm).toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith(id);
    let snackbar = document.querySelector('simple-snack-bar');
    expect(snackbar).toBeTruthy();
   
    snackbar?.querySelector('button')?.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();
    expect(service.unconfirm).toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith(id);
}));
```

Comment: I've tried with async and tick, this changes nothing

Comment: Please make sure that the selected snackbar button exists, you can remove the optional '?' from snackbar and button, because they should be truthy for this to work. Also you can spy on 'ref.afterDismissed()' to see if it is called after click. If not, maybe you can trigger it some other way.

Comment: According to the logs, the button exists and afterDismissed is called, but it seems like jasmine doesn't see it

Answer (score 0):

*FakeAsync* and *tick* will probably do the trick.  Alternatively, consider rewriting  **confirm** so that it returns the observable, instead of subscribing to it.  This will make the method more flexible, and then inside the test you can just call Jasmine's **done** callback or make the method async and convert the observable to a promise.

**Component**

```
confirm(id: number): Observable<unknown> {
  return this.service.confirm(id).pipe(
    switchMap(success => {
      const ref = this.snackbarService.open('Confirmed successfully', 'Undo confirm');
      return forkJoin([of(success), ref.afterDismissed()]);
    }),
    filter(([cancelable, dismiss]) => cancelable && dismiss.dismissedByAction),
    switchMap(() => this.service.unconfirm(id)),
    // make sure snackbar from subscribe is called.
    tap(() => this.snackbarService.open('Undone successfully', 'Close'))
  );
}
```

**Test Option 1: done callback**

```
it('when ... should show action canceled success snackbar', (done) => {
  const service = TestBed.inject(Service);
  spyOn(service, 'confirm').and.callThrough();
  spyOn(service, 'unconfirm').and.callThrough();

  const id = 1;

  component.confirm(id).subscribe(() => {
    expect(service.confirm).toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith(id);
    let snackbar = document.querySelector('simple-snack-bar');
    expect(snackbar).toBeTruthy();

    snackbar?.querySelector('button')?.click();
    expect(service.unconfirm).toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith(id);
    done();
  });
});
```

**Test Option 2: async function**

```
it('when ... should show action canceled success snackbar', async () => {
  const service = TestBed.inject(Service);
  spyOn(service, 'confirm').and.callThrough();
  spyOn(service, 'unconfirm').and.callThrough();

  const id = 1;

  await firstValueFrom(component.confirm(id));    
  expect(service.confirm).toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith(id);
  let snackbar = document.querySelector('simple-snack-bar');
  expect(snackbar).toBeTruthy();
  snackbar?.querySelector('button')?.click();
  expect(service.unconfirm).toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith(id);
});
```

Comment: I notice the rewriting, but I can't click on the button into my subscription, at this time the snackbar already disappeared isn't it?